# Can't find my application in gnome-shell "frequent" app group

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I suppose my problem is mostly gnome related.

I've created GUI application myself and create shortcut (.desktop file) for it. 
It works flawlessly on Unity. But on gnome-shell I can't find it in app history. GNOME can find application with app search or in "All" tab. But it is never appears inside "Frequent" tab.

I can't find why. Here is my desktop:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gate.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pro Gate
Comment=Pro Gate client
Exec=/opt/gate/gateclient
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gate_logo_256x256.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
```

I look into many other .desktop files but still have no clue why my desktop is special to the GNOME? Most of the entries have no such problem.
The only thing I've found is that I am not alone. Qt Maintainance tool is also the one damned by this curse. At the same time Qt Creator can be seen in history.